# How can i add property to already declared function's parameter type inside imported interface? TS2322

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-directives

I'm importing [DirectiveOptions](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/types/options.d.ts#L194) from `vue` types.

Which has few functions with [DirectiveFunction](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/types/options.d.ts#L187) type.

This [DirectiveFunction](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/types/options.d.ts#L187) first parameter is `HTMLElement`. But i do not import this function type, i need to extend or add property to this functions first parameter.

How do I add a property to this `HTMLElement` type?

[Here is code sandbox where the error occurs](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-poincare-yk6hj?file=/src/directive.ts)

```
import { DirectiveOptions } from 'vue'

interface HTMLElement {
    doStuff: (event: any) => void
}

const directive: DirectiveOptions = {
    bind(elem: HTMLElement, bind, vn){
        elem.doStuff = (event)=> {
            console.log('doing stuff')
        }
        document.body.addEventListener('click', elem.doStuff )
    },
    unbind(elem){
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', elem.doStuff)
    }
}
```

Compiler says **Property 'doStuff' is missing in type 'HTMLElement' but required in type 'HTMLElement'** because HTMLElement was already declared inside DirectiveOptions function parameter.

Even if I follow answer and create new interface extending `HTMLElement` same error occurs.

```
interface HTMLElementWithDoStuff extends HTMLElement {
  doStuff: (event: any) => void;
}

const directive: DirectiveOptions = {
  bind(elem: HTMLElementWithDoStuff, bind, vn) {
    elem.doStuff = (event) => {
      console.log("doing stuff");
    };
    document.body.addEventListener("click", elem.doStuff);
  },
  unbind(elem: HTMLElementWithDoStuff) {
    document.body.removeEventListener("click", elem.doStuff);
  }
};
```

Property 'doStuff' is missing in type 'HTMLElement' but required in type 'HTMLElementWithDoStuff'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the trick is that you need to create a new variable as a new type and not assign it in params.

```
interface HTMLElementWithDoStuff extends HTMLElement {
  doStuff: (event: any) => void;
}

const directive: DirectiveOptions = {
  bind(el, bind, vn) {
    const elem = el as ExtendedHTMLElement
    elem.doStuff = (event) => {
      console.log("doing stuff");
    };
    document.body.addEventListener("click", elem.doStuff);
  },
  unbind(el) {
    const elem = el as ExtendedHTMLElement
    document.body.removeEventListener("click", elem.doStuff);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a bad idea to alter existing types, especially types that come from places external to your app.

You should create your own type that `extends HTMLElement`, add your property to it, and then use that new type.

```
interface HTMLElementWithDoStuff extends HTMLElement {
  doStuff: (event: any) => void;
}
```

Then you use that type in the file where you need that method to exist.

```
const directive: DirectiveOptions = {
  bind(elem: HTMLElementWithDoStuff, bind, vn) {
    elem.doStuff = (event) => {
      console.log("doing stuff");
    };
    document.body.addEventListener("click", elem.doStuff);
  },
  unbind(elem: HTMLElementWithDoStuff) {
    document.body.removeEventListener("click", elem.doStuff);
  }
};
```

Now typescript will enforce that any `HTMLElement` passed in will have a `doStuff` method on it as well.

[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-snow-o2suv?file=/src/directive.ts)

Comment: I've tried creating and extending my own types of `HTMLElement`,`DirectiveOptions` and `DirectiveFunction`. The thing is `elem` parameter of `bind` and `unbind` function typed with HTMLElement and compiler errors with *TS2322:* *Property 'doStuff' is missing in type 'HTMLElement' but required in type 'HTMLElementWithDoStuff'*

Comment: The sandbox I posted at the end of my answer shows no errors. Can you link the sandbox where you are seeing errors with this solution?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me in advance, it's the `{ "strict": true }` compiler option inside tsconfig.json. Sandbox's default `tsconfig.json` does not include that field by default and if I set it, this error is present, how should I proceed with `{ "strict": true }` [Forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-poincare-lh3el?file=/src/directive.ts)